# Does scanf modify unmatched corresponding arguments?

Tags: scanf

Given the following code and assuming the only input is the letter A followed by a newline, scanf should return 0 due to a matching failure:

```
int x;
scanf("%d", &x);
```

My question is whether scanf is legally allowed to alter the value of x even if nothing in the input matches the %d format as long as it still returns 0.  The language standard doesn't seem to address this issue so my first impression is that the answer is no.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By careful reading of the standard definition, the function only modifies the pointed values when the scan is successful. `scanf("%d %d %d", &a, &b, &c)` should not modify `b` if the return value is less than 2.